# Find submatrices of matrix containing nan values such that largest amount of known values is covered by submatrices

Tags: matlab, submatrix, tiling

Given a matrix of arbitrary dimensions where under a certain antidiagonal all values are unknown, `NaN`, I want to extract submatrices without `NaN` values which are as large as possible such that as many elements of the original matrix are contained in the submatrices. Each submatrix must be at least `R` by `R`, where `R` can be specified by the user. The submatrices may overlap each other. I'm able to find the anti-diagonal under which all elements are NaN, but I don't really know how to divide the non-NaN part of the matrix in submatrices which try to cover as much of the known values as possible.

The following image illustrates how the numeric part of the matrix might be partly divided in submatrices for `R = 3`:
[Possible submatrix division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohnfG.png)

I have the following code:

```
mask = ~isnan(A);
nrKnownElsRow = sum(mask,2);
dims = [[1:length(nrKnownElsRow)]' nrKnownElsRow];
dims(dims(:,2)<R,:) = [];
dims(dims(:,1)<R,:) = [];
idx = find(dims(:,2) == max(dims(:,2)));
dims(idx(1:end-1),:) = [];
dims = [dims(:,1) zeros(length(dims),1) dims(:,2)];

for k = 1:length(dims)-1
    if dims(k,3) - dims(k+1,3) >= R
        dims(k,2) = dims(k+1,3) + 1;
    else
        dims(k,2) = dims(k,3) - R + 1;
    end
end
dims(end,2) = 1;
```

The `dims` variable contains in each row for the corresponding submatrix the row up to which the subtensor goes, then the outer columns that make up the submatrix. This uses the most information possible in the matrix, but the submatrices are not as large as possible.

Comment: As currently stated, the largest matrix containing as many elements from the original matrix, is your original matrix. Are you looking for a matrix containing no Nan value? How big is your matrix in the real application?

Comment: @BillBokeey Yes, I am indeed looking for submatrices without NaN values, I also edited this in my post, thank you! The size of the matrix can vary, as well as the location of the antidiagonal. The code should be able to handle matrices of arbitrary dimensions, with variable antidiagonal location and for any R specified by the user.

Comment: [`diag(A,k)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) extracts elements on the `k`th diagonal of `A`. If I understand your question correct, all you need to do is loop over `all(~isnan(diag(A,k)))` for as many diagonals as you need

Comment: @Adriaan I don't think you understood my question correctly. The code should return submatrices of the original matrix, your snippet just returns whether a certain diagonal of A only contains values without NaN.

Comment: Which is the first step of your question, isn't it? You want to find diagonals without `nan` values, then return those submatrices. My previous comment solves the first part

Comment: Your code indeed finds a diagonal without NaN values, however this was not the part of the problem I'm having trouble with. I do admit that I should have specified this more clearly, I'll add this to my post. The difficult part is extracting submatrices from the non-NaN part of the matrix such that as much 'area' of the known part is covered and whilst respecting the minimum required dimensions of the submatrices as specified in my post.

Comment: @StijnCastelyns I'm not clear on what result you're looking for. In the image you attached, are you looking for M1, M2 or M3? Or all three of them? If all three, why did you not add submatrices M4 through M10? Or are you simply looking for the submatrix that has the maximum number of elements?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is not perfect but it may help you get started.

This script catches all submatrixes with 1 or both sides > `r` (the threshold you defined as R).

```
close all;clear all;clc

N1=10;N2=10  % A size
% avoid N1=1 N2=1

r=3; % threshold
```

generating `A`

```
A=reshape(randi([1 10],1,N1*N2),N1,N2); % generating A
n0=randi([1 5],1,1)            % define amount NaN to scatter in A
% n0=1 % test
n1=randi([2 N1-1],1,n0);
n2=randi([2 N2-1],1,n0);
A(sub2ind([N1 N2],n1,n2))=NaN
```

find NaNs coordinates

```
A2=isnan(A);
[nan_row,nan_col]=find(A2>0)
nan_row=sort(nan_row);nan_col=sort(nan_col);

% calculate coordinates combinations, no repetition
L1=[1 1;nan_row,nan_col;N1 N2];
L2x=nchoosek(L1(:,2),2) % 1D coord combinations
L2y=nchoosek(L1(:,1),2)
```

Now `L2x` and `L2y` contain all single-coordinate combinations

combining `L2x` and `L2y` into single variable `L3`

```
[cx,cy]=meshgrid([1:1:size(L2x,1)],[1:1:size(L2y,1)])

L3=[L2x(cx(:),:) L2y(cy(:),:)]      

trim borders of all submatrixes
for k1=1:1:size(L3,1)                  
    if L3(k1,1)==1 && L3(k1,2)<N1
        L3(k1,2)=L3(k1,2)-1;
    end
    if L3(k1,1)>1 && L3(k1,2)==N1
        L3(k1,1)=L3(k1,1)+1;
    end
    if L3(k1,1)>1 && L3(k1,2)<N1
        L3(k1,1)=L3(k1,1)-1;
        L3(k1,2)=L3(k1,2)+1;
    end
end
for k1=1:1:size(L3,1)                 
    if L3(k1,3)==1 && L3(k1,4)<N2
        L3(k1,4)=L3(k1,4)-1;
    end
    if L3(k1,3)>1 && L3(k1,4)==N2
        L3(k1,3)=L3(k1,3)+1;
    end
    if L3(k1,3)>1 && L3(k1,4)<N2
        L3(k1,3)=L3(k1,3)-1;
        L3(k1,4)=L3(k1,4)+1;
    end
end
% L3
```

remove any submatrix containing NaNs

```
cnan=zeros(1,size(L3,1))
for k3=1:1:numel(cnan)
    A4=A(L3(k3,3):L3(k3,4),L3(k3,1):L3(k3,2))
    if nonzeros(isnan(A4));
        cnan(k3)=1   % contains NaN(s)
    end
end
L3(cnan>0,:)=[]
```

calculating all submatrix combinations, pairs, no repetition

```
nL3=nchoosek(size(L3,1),2)  % how many pairs
cnL3=nchoosek([1:size(L3,1)],2)
```

attaching marker to each `cnL3` line telling whether a1(a2), or a2(a1), or a1==a2.

`cnL3` format : `[ ...  A51_contains_A52 A52_contains_A51]`

```
cnL3=[cnL3 zeros(size(cnL3,1),2)]
```

who contains who

```
for k3=1:1:nL3
    d1=L3(cnL3(k3,1),:)
    d2=L3(cnL3(k3,2),:)
    
    if (d1(1)<d2(1) && d1(2)>d2(2) && d1(3)<d2(3) && d1(4)>d2(4)) || ...  % A51 contains A52
       (d1(1)<=d2(1) && d1(2)>=d2(2) && d1(3)<=d2(3) && d1(4)>d2(4)) || ...  % 3 side    
       (d1(1)<=d2(1) && d1(2)>=d2(2) && d1(3)<d2(3) && d1(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d1(1)<=d2(1) && d1(2)>d2(2) && d1(3)<=d2(3) && d1(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d1(1)<d2(1) && d1(2)>=d2(2) && d1(3)<=d2(3) && d1(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d1(1)<=d2(1) && d1(2)>=d2(2) && d1(3)<d2(3) && d1(4)>d2(4)) || ...    % 2 side
       (d1(1)<=d2(1) && d1(2)>d2(2) && d1(3)<d2(3) && d1(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d1(1)<d2(1) && d1(2)>d2(2) && d1(3)<=d2(3) && d1(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d1(1)<d2(1) && d1(2)>=d2(2) && d1(3)<=d2(3) && d1(4)>d2(4)) || ...
       (d1(1)<=d2(1) && d1(2)>d2(2) && d1(3)<d2(3) && d1(4)>d2(4)) || ...   % 1 side
       (d1(1)<d2(1) && d1(2)>d2(2) && d1(3)<d2(3) && d1(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d1(1)<d2(1) && d1(2)>d2(2) && d1(3)<=d2(3) && d1(4)>d2(4)) || ...
       (d1(1)<d2(1) && d1(2)>=d2(2) && d1(3)<d2(3) && d1(4)>d2(4))
          cnL3(k3,3)=1; 
    end
  
    if (d2(1)<d2(1) && d2(2)>d2(2) && d2(3)<d2(3) && d2(4)>d2(4)) || ...   % A52 contains A51
       (d2(1)<=d2(1) && d2(2)>=d2(2) && d2(3)<=d2(3) && d2(4)>d2(4)) || ...    
       (d2(1)<=d2(1) && d2(2)>=d2(2) && d2(3)<d2(3) && d2(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d2(1)<=d2(1) && d2(2)>d2(2) && d2(3)<=d2(3) && d2(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d2(1)<d2(1) && d2(2)>=d2(2) && d2(3)<=d2(3) && d2(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d2(1)<=d2(1) && d2(2)>=d2(2) && d2(3)<d2(3) && d2(4)>d2(4)) || ...    
       (d2(1)<=d2(1) && d2(2)>d2(2) && d2(3)<d2(3) && d2(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d2(1)<d2(1) && d2(2)>d2(2) && d2(3)<=d2(3) && d2(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d2(1)<d2(1) && d2(2)>=d2(2) && d2(3)<=d2(3) && d2(4)>d2(4)) || ...
       (d2(1)<=d2(1) && d2(2)>d2(2) && d2(3)<d2(3) && d2(4)>d2(4)) || ...   
       (d2(1)<d2(1) && d2(2)>d2(2) && d2(3)<d2(3) && d2(4)>=d2(4)) || ...
       (d2(1)<d2(1) && d2(2)>d2(2) && d2(3)<=d2(3) && d2(4)>d2(4)) || ...
       (d2(1)<d2(1) && d2(2)>=d2(2) && d2(3)<d2(3) && d2(4)>d2(4))
          cnL3(k3,4)=1; 
    end
    
    % A51=A(d1(3):d1(4),d1(1):d1(2)) % checks
    % A52=A(d2(3):d2(4),d2(1):d2(2))
  
end
```

pairs with contained submatrixes

```
[drow,dcol]=find(cnL3(:,3)==1 | cnL3(:,4)==1)
```

removing contained submatrixes from submatrix list `L3`

```
cnt=[]
for k3=1:1:numel(drow)
    L5=cnL3(drow(k3),:);
    if L5(3)==1 cnt=[cnt L5(2)]; end
    if L5(4)==1 cnt=[cnt L5(1)]; end
end
cnt=unique(cnt)
L4=L3
L4(cnt,:)=[]
L4
```

`X` : cell containing all complying submatrices

```
X={}    
for k1=1:1:size(L4,1)
    X=[X A(L4(k1,3):L4(k1,4),L4(k1,1):L4(k1,2))];
end
X
```

reading 1 element of cell `X`

```
X{1}
```

how to do a cell all-out

```
X{:}
```

Just typing `X` MATLAB returns all sizes of elements inside cell `X`

```
just example 
X 
=
1×4 cell array
Columns 1 through 2
{10×5 double}    {7×10 double}
Columns 3 through 4
{2×10 double}    {10×4 double}
```

now the threshold `r` you required

```
XR=X;
L5=diff(L4,1,2)+1  % calculating sizes
L5(:,[2:2:end])=[]
[rrow,rcol]=find(L5<r)
XR(rrow)=[]
XR{:}
```

This works for the few cases I checked.

Note I generate test matrixes with no NaNs along perimeter.

Stijn, if this solution helps would you please be so kind to consider green-ticking it as valid answer?

thanks for reading